# Rails - Cant get errors to display on a failed ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to get this for a while now but cant get any errors to display when a user submits a form via ajax and the form fails (I cant get a success message to display either but thats not as big of a deal).

Here is what I have

The form

```
<ul id="errors">

</ul>

<%= form_for([@guide, @category, @key], url: guide_categories_keycreate_path(category_id: params[:id]), remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Key name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.select :key_type, [['Value', 1], ['Text', 2], ['Image', 3]] %>

   <%= f.submit "Next", :value => "Add New Key"  %>
<% end %>
```

The js render line in the controller on if key doesn't save

```
...
else
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html {  redirect_to edit_guide_category_path(@guide, @category) }
          format.json { render :json => { :error => @key.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422 }
     format.js 
  end
```

javascript

```
$(document).on "ajax:error", "form", (evt, xhr, status, error) ->
   errors = xhr.responseJSON.error
   for message of errors
      $('#errors ul').append '<li>' + errors[message] + '</li>'
```

The form isn't in its normal key/create view, incase something in the code confuses you that might explain why it's that way.

Dont know where to go from here, I basically copied the coding from [this](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/ajax-and-json-error-handling-on-rails/) tutorial. I have looked at and tried a few tutorials and seen a few stackoverflow questions and this is basically all I need but wont work. Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely here:

```
$('#errors ul').append '<li>' + errors[message] + '</li>'
```

It should be

```
$('ul#errors').append '<li>' + errors[message] + '</li>'
```

Whenever you call an element by its `id` or `class`, if the class is on the element itself, you need to reference the element before the identifier; if the identifier is *inside* the element, you can use your way:

```
<ul class="errors">
  <li class="test">...</li>
</ul>

$("ul#errors")  #-> selects ul with id of errors
$("ul .test")   #-> selects all nested elements with "test" class
```

---

> Not sure what to do next.

You need to debug.

The overview of your issue could be fixed with the following:

1. See what requests / responses are being sent through your development console
2. Determine if there are any errors in the flow (like I mentioned above)
3. Ensure your controllers are giving appropriate responses

The way I'd debug is as follows:

--

**Console**

You need to make sure you know what's going on in your app; you also have all the tools to do it. Firstly, you need to make sure you know which requests are being sent. Do this through the [developer console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

In both Firefox & Chrome..

```
Right Click > Inspect Element > Console > "Network" (tab)
```

When you go on this tab, and click "submit" on your remote form, you'll see the request (and response) appear. You can use this to determine what is wrong:

[image]

You can read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network).

-

**JS**

Secondly, you could have an issue with your flow.

With the above code, you're only sending a `JS` request (not `JSON`). If you want `JSON`, you'd have to set the `type` as follows:

```
<%= form_for [@guide, @category, @key], url: guide_categories_keycreate_path(category_id: params[:id]), remote: true, authenticity_token: true, data: { type: :json }  do |f| %>
```

You also need to make sure your JS is correctly formatted (my first point).

Ultimately, I cannot comb through every line of code - you need to use the tools I've outlined to see what the issue might be.

-

**Controller**

Finally, the last issue might be with the controller.

Whilst unlikely, you may not be sending the correctly formatted request etc; leading your controller to send an incorrect response.

I would strongly recommend using your Rails console to see what's going wrong:

[image]

Each time you send a request to your app, the console log should record it. Thus, if you have *any* issue, you need to check out what issues are being recorded. If you posted that, it would give a lot better insight into what's going on

Comment: Wow great answer! I'll give it a crack. You have helped me out heaps. I have one more problem I have been spending all day on with no luck. Its a nested form that stopped working god knows when (tests pass). I cant figure out what has caused it to now only pass the id on the form submit and nothing else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400048/rails-nested-forms-only-passing-the-id-on-form-submit