# Rails nested forms only passing the id on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller, nested-forms

No idea whats going wrong here. From memory it used to work fine but I just recently used the form and realised it has stopped working somewhere in the process of building the app. Mini test still passes it which could mean it is something trivial or on the form directly.

I'm trying to get the nested attribute `value` to pass on the from submit

**category_item model**

```
  has_many :category_item_values, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_item_values

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

**category_item_value model**

```
  belongs_to :category_item
```

**category_items/edit.html.erb**

```
   <%= form_for([@category, @category_item], url: category_items_update_path) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <%= f.fields_for :category_item_values do |item_value| %>


  <div class="value_fields">
  <%=  item_value.object.key %><br>
     <%= item_value.label :value %> 
     <%= item_value.text_field :value %>
  </div> 

    <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Save"%>
  <% end %>
```

**category_item controller**

```
def edit

     @guide         = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
     @category      = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
     @category_item = @category.category_items.friendly.find params[:id]

end

def update


     @guide         = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
     @category      = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
     @category_item = @category.category_items.friendly.find params[:id]

    if @category_item.update (item_params)
      flash[:success] = "Updated. Thanks for contributing!"
      redirect_to category_items_show_path(@guide, @category, @category_item)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

end

private

def item_params
   params.require(:category_item).permit(:name, category_item_values_attributes: [:id, :value])
end
```

**parpamters passed when the form is submitted**

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"O/+jbpxxY9ACV1+M7SQoYXHGvhOlgT/SufGoFpjTKaxqewnQ0IKRJWF+kxoE99DCaiKYPVkKtctSrQ0hPegIEw==", "category_item"=>{"category_item_values_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"39"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"40"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"41"}, "3"=>{"id"=>"42"}, "4"=>{"id"=>"43"}, "5"=>{"id"=>"44"}, "6"=>{"id"=>"45"}, "7"=>{"id"=>"46"}, "8"=>{"id"=>"47"}, "9"=>{"id"=>"48"}, "10"=>{"id"=>"49"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "guide_id"=>"dungeon-boss", "category_id"=>"heroes", "id"=>"smok"}
```

**The mini test that passes**

```
  test "mod editing all category items successfully" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get category_items_edit_path(@guide, @category, @category_item)
    assert_template 'category_items/edit'
    assert_select 'form.edit_category_item'
    assert CategoryItemValue.find(1).value == 'simmv' #confirm value before edit
    patch category_items_update_path(params: {key_id: 1}), category_item: { category_item_values_attributes:  [id: 1, value: "333"]}
    assert CategoryItemValue.find(1).value == '333' #confirm value changed after edit
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'category_items/show'
    assert_select 'div.alert'
  end
```

Been over it a few times but cant figure out how to get the `value` nested attribute to pass into the params and db from the form submit.

categroy_item_values schema

```
create_table "category_item_values", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "key"
    t.integer  "key_type"
    t.text     "value"
    t.integer  "category_item_key_id"
    t.integer  "category_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end
```

*Here is the log of loading the page then submitting the form

```
Started GET "/guides/dungeon-boss/heroes/rock/edit" for ::1 at 2016-02-16 21:59:16 +1100
Processing by CategoryItemsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"guide_id"=>"dungeon-boss", "category_id"=>"heroes", "id"=>"rock"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mGuide Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "guides"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["slug", "dungeon-boss"]]
  [1m[35mCategory Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "heroes"]]
  [1m[36mGameModsRelationship Exists (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "game_mods_relationships" WHERE "game_mods_relationships"."user_id" = ? AND "game_mods_relationships"."category_id" = 7 LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCategoryItem Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "category_items".* FROM "category_items" WHERE "category_items"."category_id" = ? AND "category_items"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "category_items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["category_id", 3], ["slug", "rock"]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "game_mods_relationships" WHERE "game_mods_relationships"."user_id" = ? AND "game_mods_relationships"."category_id" = 7 LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  [1m[35mCategoryItemValue Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "category_item_values".* FROM "category_item_values" WHERE "category_item_values"."category_item_id" = ?  [["category_item_id", 10]]
  Rendered category_items/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (19.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 230ms (Views: 221.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started PATCH "/guides/dungeon-boss/heroes/rock" for ::1 at 2016-02-16 21:59:21 +1100
Processing by CategoryItemsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fT4HylfaCf9ONVlRYLKP9jP4nlerxMZoyyYJkx0mDkwsuq10Gyn7Ci0clceJYXdVKBy4eVdPTHEgeqykuB0v8w==", "category_item"=>{"category_item_values_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"28"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"29"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"30"}, "3"=>{"id"=>"31"}, "4"=>{"id"=>"32"}, "5"=>{"id"=>"33"}, "6"=>{"id"=>"34"}, "7"=>{"id"=>"35"}, "8"=>{"id"=>"36"}, "9"=>{"id"=>"37"}, "10"=>{"id"=>"38"}, "11"=>{"id"=>"39"}, "12"=>{"id"=>"40"}, "13"=>{"id"=>"41"}, "14"=>{"id"=>"42"}, "15"=>{"id"=>"43"}, "16"=>{"id"=>"44"}, "17"=>{"id"=>"45"}, "18"=>{"id"=>"46"}, "19"=>{"id"=>"47"}, "20"=>{"id"=>"48"}, "21"=>{"id"=>"49"}, "22"=>{"id"=>"50"}, "23"=>{"id"=>"51"}, "24"=>{"id"=>"52"}, "25"=>{"id"=>"53"}, "26"=>{"id"=>"54"}, "27"=>{"id"=>"55"}, "28"=>{"id"=>"56"}, "29"=>{"id"=>"57"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "guide_id"=>"dungeon-boss", "category_id"=>"heroes", "id"=>"rock"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[35mGuide Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "guides"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "dungeon-boss"]]
  [1m[36mGameModsRelationship Exists (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "game_mods_relationships" WHERE "game_mods_relationships"."user_id" = ? AND "game_mods_relationships"."category_id" = 7 LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[35mCategory Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "heroes"]]
  [1m[36mCategoryItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "category_items".* FROM "category_items" WHERE "category_items"."category_id" = ? AND "category_items"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "category_items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["category_id", 3], ["slug", "rock"]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "game_mods_relationships" WHERE "game_mods_relationships"."user_id" = ? AND "game_mods_relationships"."category_id" = 7 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mCategoryItemValue Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "category_item_values".* FROM "category_item_values" WHERE "category_item_values"."category_item_id" = ? AND "category_item_values"."id" IN (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57)  [["category_item_id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCategoryItem Exists (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "category_items" WHERE (LOWER("category_items"."name") = LOWER('rock') AND "category_items"."id" != 10 AND "category_items"."guide_id" = 7) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/guides/dungeon-boss/heroes/rock
Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Everything seems to work fine. Also when I manually give `value` a value in the db it shows up in the forms input to be edited, so the form seems to be working correctly. Its just when I hit submit it wont add `value` into the attributed parameters hash.

There is a bit going on in the log so if something confuses that you think might cause the problem just ask (I have a bad habit of assuming people know about parts of a random add they cant see).

Comment: Strange. Are you perhaps using a different version of your code than what you're looking at in your editor (like a different git branch)? In your form, is the `<% end %>` for the `form_for` the next line, or is there more that you aren't showing to the form?

Comment: Thought I might have removed the other `<% end %>` from the nested form  by accident but I just forgot to paste it into my question. Fixed the question.

Comment: Are `category_item_values` hashes that are being stored in database? Or do they simply have the fields `:id`, `:key` and `:value`? Better yet, can you just post the schema for `category_item_values`?

Comment: From what I'm seeing, everything looks fine for the `:value` attribute to at least be present in the `params` hash. Other than making sure you are looking at the `params` hash for the correct request, and maybe simply restarting the server to see if that fixes something, I've got nothing. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Even saying you got nothing means it could most likely be some deeper problem with the app setup that I'm overlooking and confirms its not just a obvious coding issue.

Comment: I can confirm it looks okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for [@category, @category_item], url: category_items_update_path do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <%= f.fields_for :category_item_values do |item_value| %>
     <%= item_value.object.key %>
     <%= item_value.label :value %> 
     <%= item_value.text_field :value %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit "Save"%>
<% end %>
```

Whenever you create code, you need to ensure it's [indented properly](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout).

*This* code is good; the likely issue is that you're using outdated code from some other view / action. If you posted your entire console log for the request, we could give you a more appropriate answer.

---

```
"guide_id"=>"dungeon-boss", "category_id"=>"heroes", "id"=>"smok"
```

This is from your params. This does not look like `category_items_update_path`; perhaps it will help you identify the view that's being used.

Comment: Thanks for giving this one a look. This one is frustrating me so much. I added the log of the page loading and submitting the form into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, do you have a `git` repo I could peruse?

Comment: If you have a bitbucket username I can send you an invite.

Comment: I sent you an invite to the repo. But I warn you I'm no pro rails developer and the project is in early days so its a little messy in there.

Comment: No problem, let me check i tout

Comment: Ok I used your email this time.

Comment: Wait I sent you to the wrong project. its the wikisite one

Comment: did you get around to looking at it?

Comment: Never mind I found the problem. Thanks for going above and beyond for me

Answer (score 0):

After searching high and low for a few days I managed to find the culprit was a bit of coffee script coding in a .coffee file. This coffescript was using jquery to change the way the forms html was ordered on the page making the part of the form html all jumbled. The coffeescript wasnt necessary (I was just playing around with jquery and forgot to get rid the coding a while back) so I removed it and voila, problem solved.