# How to stop friendly id from generating a numeric sequence to differentiate conflicting slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, friendly-id

Say I have a uniqueness constraint on `name` inside its has_many association. This would mean I don't need the ugly numeric sequence added to conflicting slugs.

As an example 2 slugs might get the same name in a `game` db from 2 different people having a game called 'cards' `/person/1/games/cards` and `person/2/games/cards` these are 2 different URLs but the slug on the second will look like `person/2/game/cards2bc08962-b3dd-4f29-b2e6-244710c86106`. person has a name uniqueness constraint on the name of their games so they cant have 2 games called 'cards' which stops 2 of the same slug being generated.

Problem is that the name of the games are all sorted in the one db so the conflicting slugs will have the numeric sequence added when its not needed, so urls become unnecessarily ugly.

Hope that made sense as to why I want it.

Anyway. How can I stop the numeric sequence from being added to conflicting slugs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [scoped functionality](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Scoped)

```
class Card
   friendly_id :name, :use => :scoped, :scope => [:person]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the accepted answer, there is also the [`slug_candidates`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50) method:

```
#app/models/card.rb
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :person_id]
    ]
  end
end
```

The above will create:

```
#url.com/players/1/games/cards
#url.com/players/2/games/cards-2
```

Whilst not as good as `scoped` for what you need, it will give you some options with other implementations.

Comment: Literally just realised I need something like this as well for another model and you game me the answer before I had to look it up. Also I saw this in the github docs looking for my answer to the question but skimmed over it thinking it was for some other purpose.

Comment: You should also make sure you look up about the [`history`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History) module for `friendly_id`. It's a separate db which stores all the historic slugs; most skip it but it's required for using `scope`

Comment: Thanks! I've been stuck on another question for a couple days now, can you give it a quick look over? If you don't know just leave it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378426/rails-cant-get-errors-to-display-on-a-failed-ajax-form-submit